# How to change TinyMce default css path?

Tags: tinymce

How do I change the default css path for the theme that tiny mce use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default path is `tiny_mce/themes/your_selected_theme` and as for now there is no way to set the path to any other place. Thus, you will need to place your theme there.